# Heroku deployment crashing at start Nodejs

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am trying to deploy my existing `NodeJS` application to `heroku`. I followed all the process listed in the documentation.

I wrote this on my procfile:

```
web: node ./bin/www
```

but I am constantly getting:

> Process exited with status 1
>   2016-08-08T11:07:54.028983+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
>   2016-08-08T11:07:56.852268+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=agile-headland-49936.herokuapp.com request_id=357f1a83-adff-4353-8e6b-6f8166cdb09b fwd="202.166.207.112" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

Comment: What are the full error logs / stack trace of your app's crash?

Comment: How do you start your NodeJS application locally? I would expect something like `node app.js` (a JavaScript file, not a directory like www).

Answer (score 1):

`web: node ./bin/www` this gives me a hint that you are making an **Express App**. Your `package.json` might have something like:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
 }
```

You can just place `web: npm start` in your **Procfile**. This should work. Hope this helps :)

Comment: if you just want to to run the npm start command, a procfile is not needed . Heroku by default executes `web: npm start` command

from [heroku procfile documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile)

*Deploying to Heroku
A Procfile is not necessary to deploy apps written in most languages supported by Heroku. The platform automatically detects the language, and creates a default web process type to boot the application server.
Creating an explicit Procfile is recommended for greater control and flexibility over your app.*